# Metaballs show in rendered viewport but not in actual render?

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, meta-objects

I have a particle system that emits metaballs in Blender 2.8 eevee. My settings:

[image]

They don't show up in the render - not the object itself nor the metaballs emitted. In the rendered view they show up:

[image]

But in render, nothing:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Is [viewport visibility on and render vis off](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/outliner.html#object-level-restrictions)? I don't have an issue rendering metaballs with current master, your copy of 2.80 is looking a bit old.

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved this by now but in case anyone is wondering - I had the same issue with emitting metaballs showing up fine in the viewport but not rendering. In my case the emitter object had rigid body physics enabled. Once I disabled that the problem was solved and metaballs rendered fine